# Confusion regarding notation in proof of Sylow's First Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

On pg.93 of Herstein's "Topics in Algebra", we have $H\leq G$. Then the author talks about $no(H)$.

What is $no(H)$? I haven't come across this notation before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find the notation $|H|$ for the order of a group much more useful. As you can see, $o(H)$ gets mixed up with letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is $n$ times the order of $H$; it is unfortunate typesetting, combined with  Herstein's (in my opinion, strange) decision to refer to the cardinality of $H$ with the notation $o(H)$.